# Replace spaces with colon (:) in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, regex

***Suppose*** (this is sample data) I have these lines:

```
A                          W
BAKER                      X
CANDLESTICKMAKER           Y
DOGCATCHER                 Z
```

I want to change the whitespace to colons, like this:

```
A:W
BAKER:X
CANDLESTICKMAKER:Y
DOGCATCHER:Z
```

How can I achieve this in Notepad++?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying edits to the question, at first I thought it was a simple Ctrl+H replace!

Answer (score 6):

Replace `+` ( followed by `+`) with `:`:

[image]

Make sure **Regular expression** is checked.

As [igalvez pointed out in his comment](https://superuser.com/questions/762723/replace-spaces-with-colon-in-notepad/762725?noredirect=1#comment987912_762725), you might want to use `( |\t)+` to also match `\t` (the tab character).

One might want to use `\s` to match *all* whitespace, but that will also match the line breaks and condense your whole data to a single line.

Comment: [Not Working](http://imgur.com/OgqhaeK)

Comment: @Farid Is there a space between the beginning and the `+` ? ie. ` +`. I can't see it in the picture.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg nope

Comment: @Farid I'm shub ;) Add the space and it should work :)

Comment: I made space using "spacebar" for two lines..and made space using "Tab" for other two lines....this didn't work with Tab spaced lines..spaces created with "Tab" key won't go away...

Comment: @ISAAC Using this search pattern will catch tab characters as well: `( |\t)+`

Answer (score 0):

Before replacing ' +' with ':' go to Edit->blank operations->ΤΑΒ to space. Then it should work as expected.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.  You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).